React useState re-run all my functions multiple times
I am learning NextJs & React.
And I found an interesting behaviour of React.

Whenever I click the "click me" button, it changes state which is test.
Then totally non-related code someTest is executed again.
someTest has react-query and fetch and whenever test changes, fetch is called. (I find this weird.)
I feel potentially lots of waste might cause due to this behaviour. Imagine that someTest has many processes such as multiple fetches and loops. How can I prevent? (ex: when test is changed, someTest should not be executed)

// page.tsx
'use client';

import { useSomeTest, } from "@/hooks/myHook";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function MyPage() {
  const {data: notRelatedCode} = useSomeTest();
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

  console.log(1);
  
  return <>
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {setTest(!test)}}>click me</button>
    </div>
  </>
}

// myHook.tsx
export const useSomeTest = () => {
  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['something'],
    queryFn: () => getSomething(), // fetch
    staleTime: 60 * 100,
  })
  console.log(0);
}


you are calling sometest on top of function so it calls on every re render (i.e state change here). call it in useeffect and set it to empty dependancy array so that it only calls first render

Thanks @cmgchess. Yes putting in UseEffect solves the issue. In fact "useSomeTest()" is using react-query. So it cannot be in useEffect. I updated someTest() function in my post. Can you please check this again. I'd like to know what's the best practice.

React components are essentially functions, given that, what you are saying is just expected behaviour, the content inside that function, like variables (i.e.: notRelatedCode) it's re-evaluated. This does not happen with state, which is kept between re-renders.
To avoid this, you can do something like this:
export default function MyPage() {
  const [test, setTest] = useState(false);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const notRelatedCode = await someTest();
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={(prevState) => { setTest(!prevState) }}>
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}


We use prevState param, to ensure we are using the latest state value.
We added an effect to run the someTest() only on the first render, that behavior is given by the empty dependency array at the end of useEffect.

I really encourage taking a full read of https://react.dev/ before digging into NextJS.
Once you understand the basics around react, you should probably take a look on a library that makes its easier to handle queries, specially when needing more complex behavior, like handling loading states, errors, etc.
i.e.:

Tanstack Query (aka. React Query)
SWR

Using react-query, for example, instead of needing to use an effect, you could have something like:
const { data: notRelatedCode } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['notRelatedCodeKey'],
    queryFn: someTest,
})


Thanks for your answer @maxpsz. Also thanks for the react.dev. I will carefully check. I updated my code (someTest() part). In fact I am using react-query and this cannot be inside of useEffect. How should I deal with it in that case?

I updated my answer to reflect what you asked, but I just noticed that you updated your question. The updated code seems to be pretty fine, except that someTest should be actually called useSomeTest. It's a common practice to encapsulate queries incide custom hooks, just as you are doing. If you want to get into react query best practices, I suggest you reading tkdodo's blog, he has a pretty complete post about that: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/thinking-in-react-query.

Ok so basically, changing state (useState) causes re-evaluation -> re-redering. React-query uses cache for preventing waste of re-calculation.
Thanks for the links and your advice. I learned something today @maxpsz.
